# calling a rest api on host machine from docker container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I have a pwsh docker container running and from the command line, I'm trying to call

```
 https://localhost:4432/widgets
```

The error I'm getting is

```
PS /workspaces/pwshGraphApi> Invoke-RestMethod https://localhost:4432/widgets                                            
Invoke-RestMethod: Cannot assign requested address
```

I read up and it seems it's because "localhost" in this context - inside my container - is not the same thing as localhost on the host machine.
So I tried this:

```
PS /workspaces/pwshGraphApi> Invoke-RestMethod https://host.docker.internal:4432/widgets -SkipCertificateCheck
Invoke-RestMethod: 
Bad Request

Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.
```

**Additional Information in case it helps:**

Host machine is windows 11 pro

Docker version 20.10.23, build 7155243

I'm creating a "dev container" from VSCode.  This is what the Dockerfile looks like:

```
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/microsoftgraph/powershell:latest
```

And this is what the devcontainer.json looks like:

```
 {

  "name": "GraphApiPwsh",

  // Sets the run context to one level up instead of the .devcontainer folder.
  "context": "..",

  "dockerFile": "./Dockerfile",

  // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
  "settings": {},

  // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
  "extensions": [],

  // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
  "forwardPorts": [7071, 80, 443]
}
```